# Is there any way to call function 'before document ready' in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call function before document get ready, so is there any method in Jquery to do this?

Comment: AFAIK no, but there may be ways to simulate it by placing the script at the right location. What are you trying to do, what is your end goal?

Comment: Call the function outside of document ready!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a function just before $(document).ready() triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098504/running-a-function-just-before-document-ready-triggers)

Comment: Call ur function anywhere in dom, it will be called before dom is created.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you simply call a function in the head tag it will execute immediately, before the DOM is even parsed (that's the 'problem' that `ready` solves).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>alert(1)</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 27):

Just call your function before the document ready statement.

```
<script>
   thisWillFireImmediately();

   $(function() {
      thisWillFireOnDocumentReady();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -8):

If you are using .hide() or display: none; - the hiding of the divs will be displayed.

try:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

it worked for me after trying many other ways.