# How do I have a <script> tag run before html has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The issue that I am having is this: I have a web page that has multiple pages like about, resources, etc...

I want each page to have their own stylesheet, and I do not want to load all of the pages stylesheets in the `<head>` if I don't have to.

So I came up with the idea of having a .js file run this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname == "/") {
        document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>';
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.pathname == "/about") {
        document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/about.css" type="text/css"/>';
    }
});
```

My issue is the page runs the HTML before injecting this `<link>` tag which makes for a shuttering effect of the page being loaded without css, and then switching top css. If you have any good suggestions on a way to fix this, or a better practice then I am open to Ideas. Thanks!

Comment: And what is the reason why you want to do that client and not server side?

Comment: extract the "critical" CSS (for example grid/layout, fonts) into a separate file and include that in the HTML document (server-side). There are several other techniques, such as hiding content and displaying a placeholder until the DOM is ready , then inject the CSS and reveal the actual content

Comment: To be honest I have never done it that way. Could you elaborate with node.js and express?

Comment: revealing the content after the stylesheet has been loaded: https://gist.github.com/cvan/8a188df72a95a35888b70e5fda80450d

Comment: That's what middlewares are for. Something like `app.use( (req, res, next) => { if(req.url=='/') {res.locals.stylesheet = '/Assets/css/main.css'} /* ... */ next()  })`. How exactly is out of the scope of a comment and it can't be an answer to your question, because the question is about a client side solution. So you should ask a new question, and show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply put each page's stylesheet link in the HTML of the page, rather than adding it with JavaScript. Adding it later with JavaScript will either result in a flash of unstyled content or a delay rendering the page while your JavaScript resource is loaded (since presumably you're using a common JavaScript file for this, rather than an inline script tag).

But if you have a reason for adding it with JavaScript, this is one of the few valid use cases for `document.write` during main parsing:

```
var ss = {
    "/": "main",
    "/about": "about",
    // ...
}[window.location.pathname];
if (ss) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/' + ss + '.css");
}
```

That would need to be linked in `head`:

```
<head>
<!-- ... --->
<script src="thefile.js"></script>
<!-- ... --->
</head>
```

...which is normally an anti-pattern.

Again, though: I wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () { /* code */ });
```

This actually waits for the document to be loaded.
Javascript should be executed before the document is loaded:
[Is there any way to call function 'before document ready' in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186914/is-there-any-way-to-call-function-before-document-ready-in-jquery#7186940)

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/") {
    document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>';
}


if (window.location.pathname == "/about") {
    document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/about.css" type="text/css"/>';
}
```

But as t.niese says, I would check this serverside.