# How to hide div before page loads using only Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a div before the page loads. I have added the css of `display: none;` I am overlaying the div with another one. But there is a small flash of the old div. How can I over come this, so far I have tried:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.div').hide();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.div {
 display: none; 
}
```

The div is part of some other html on the server and I can't add another class to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186914/is-there-any-way-to-call-function-before-document-ready-in-jquery - have you had a look at this?

Comment: You can't hide before page load, it first need to render the div before you can access it. There will always be flash.

Comment: "I have added the css of `display: none;`" Then it should already be hidden on page load.

Comment: @APAD1 It is not there is that flash of it showing

Comment: If you are hiding it with straight CSS there will be no flash of it showing.

Comment: There is a flash of it...

Comment: You need to explain what' going on with the html sources. Sounds like you're trying to add jquery to html you don't have access to. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: It could help if you show how your html (or at least the general structure of it) looks like. I mean the behavior may depend on order in which you `<script>` `<style>` `<link>` and `<body>` tags actually follow....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .hide() or display: none;, the hiding of the divs will be displayed.

try:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

but you will have to change them back to visible when you want them to be seen. Like this:

```
visibility: visible;
```

Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div#extraControls").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
div.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extraControls" class="hidden">test</div>
```